# LINQ compiled query struggling with nullable int

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, int, nullable, isnull

I have the following compiled Linq query:

```
public static readonly Func<DBContext, Models.User, Type, ObjectType, int?, UserNotification> GetUnreadNotificationID =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((DBContext db, Models.User forUser, Type notificationType, ObjectType forObjectType, int? forObjectID) =>
        db.UserNotifications.FirstOrDefault(c =>
            c.ForUserID == forUser.ID
            && c.ForObjectTypeID == (short)forObjectType
            && c.ForObjectID == forObjectID
            && c.TypeID == (byte)notificationType
            && c.Date > forUser.NotificationsLastRead.Date));
```

Note the parameter `int? forObjectID`.

In query profiler, an example executed SQL statement would be:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[t0].[ID], [t0].[TypeID], [t0].[ForUserID], [t0].[Date], [t0].[ForObjectTypeID], [t0].[ForObjectID], [t0].[Count]
FROM 
[dbo].[UserNotifications] AS [t0]
WHERE
([t0].[ForUserID] = @p0) 
AND ([t0].[ForObjectTypeID] = @p1) 
AND ([t0].[ForObjectID] = @p2) 
AND ([t0].[TypeID] = @p3) 
AND ([t0].[Date] > @p4)',

N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4 datetime',@p0=77812,@p1=5,@p2=NULL,@p3=4,@p4='2018-01-24 13:18:44.107'
```

When `forObjectID` is `null`, the query does not return the expected records.  If I change:

```
AND ([t0].[ForObjectID] = @p2)
```

To:

```
AND ([t0].[ForObjectID] IS NULL)
```

It does return the correct results.

- Why is null not handled in the way I would expect it to?
- Is there an easy fix?  (I can convert the table to not accept nulls for that field and default to 0 but feels icky)

Answer (score 1):

If this is Linq2Sql

change
`c.ForObjectID == forObjectID` to `Object.Equals(c.ForObjectID, forObjectID)`

for it to be able to translate to `is null` when `forObjectID` is null.

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix would be to write a SQL stored procedure which does what you want - 
I doubt that anyone will fix LinkToSql.

Or try this instead:

```
((c.ForObjectID == forObjectID) || 
 (c.ForObjectId == null && forObjectId == null))
```